# Run program but nothing comes out

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to run this program but it seems time only exit code 0.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   import random
   f = open("quiz.csv", 'r')
   Counter =0
   Content = f.read()

   Colist = Content.split("\n")
   qlist=[]
   calist=[]
   adict={}
   alist=[]
   c=0
   for i in Colist:
     if i:
         if (Counter%5 ==0):
             if(Counter!= 0):
                x = alist[0]
                random.shuffle(alist)
                calist.append(alist.index(x))
                c+=1
                alist=[]
                qlist.append(i)
             else:
                alist.append(i)
                Counter+=1

x = alist[0]
random.shuffle(alist)
adict[c]= alist
calist.append(alist.index(x))
congo =["Goodjob!","awesome!","correct"]
cnt = 0
for i in range(len(qlist)):
  print("\n question", i + 1)
  print("-------")
  print(qlist[i])
  for j in range (len(adict[1])):
    print(j+1, "->", adict[i][j])
  ch = int(input("enter your choice: "))
  if ((ch-1)==calist[i]):
       random.shuffle(congo)
       print(congo[0])
       cnt+=1
  else:
    print("sry you chose the wrong option! the correct option is",calist[i]+1)

#print("\n End of quiz ! your score is", round(cnt/len(qlist)*100,2))
```

Can some one tell me what's wrong with this code? It's a school project which I need submit within 2 days time. Please give me some advice on this as I'm stuck at this stage for a long period of time.

Comment: I suggest that you debug your code by adding `print()` statements to see what it is doing. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has more tips for debugging your code. Good luck!.

Comment: What's the format of the file?  Is it question followed by 4 answers?

Comment: Another option is to start with a new Python script and copy small, self-contained sections of the code over to it and debug them until the behavior is what you expect, then continue to add the next section of the code.

Comment: @TimRoberts yup

Comment: remember to close your file after the read

Comment: looks like alist is always empty and should main part be indented under the ```if __name__```??

Comment: @InhirCode i tried it doesn't seems to work

Comment: You aren't storing the answers anywhere.  You gather up 4 answers, shuffle them, remember the index of the correct answer, and then throw all of the answers away.

Comment: also ```if(Counter!= 0):``` to ```if (Counter!= 0):``` and if that works then ```alist``` is only appended when ```Counter == 0``` ??

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is not correct.  You're not saving the first question.  I would skip reading and splitting the file, and just let the standard file do it.

```
counter = 0
qlist = []
alist = []
for line in open("quiz.csv"):
    if line:
        if counter % 5 == 0:
            qlist.append( line )
            alist.append( [] )
        else:
            alist[-1].append( line )
            if counter % 5 == 4:
                x = alist[-1][0]
                random.shuffle(alist[-1])
                calist.append(alist[-1].index(x))
        counter += 1
```

Now you have `qlist` as the list of questions, `alist` as a list of lists, where entry `[i]` has the answers that map to question `i`, and `calist` has the index of the right answer.

Note that for this change to work, you must delete your "open", your "read", and your "split".

Comment: it seems like now it got an error                                                                                                                 question 1
-------
You're 3rd place right now in a race. What place are you in when you pass the person in 2nd place?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xinji\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\testing222.py", line 39, in <module>
    for j in range(len(adict[i])):
KeyError: 0

Comment: You will have to integrate what I've done.  You no longer need to use `adict` at all.